# Sending Email with Ajax, its not sending but saying Thank You! Your message has been sent

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Sending Email with Ajax, its not sending but saying Thank You! Your message has been sent, but not getting any email, i tried on gmail and hotmail both are not working.I have posted the form and mail.php and main.js, these are the only files for the email. I do not seem to know what the problem is, Its executing correctly but not sending email.

index.php:

```
 <form class="contact__form" method="post" action="mail.php">
                                
                                    <!-- form message -->
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-12">
                                            <div class="alert alert-success contact__msg" style="display: none" role="alert">
                                                Your message was sent successfully.
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- end message -->
    
                                    <!-- form element -->
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                                            <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                                            <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                                            <input name="phone" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone" required>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                                            <input name="subject" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject" required>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-12 form-group">
                                            <textarea name="message" class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-12">
                                            <input name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Send Message">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- end form element -->
                                </form>
```

main.js:

```
(function ($) {
    'use strict';

    var form = $('.contact__form'),
        message = $('.contact__msg'),
        form_data;

    // Success function
    function done_func(response) {
        message.fadeIn().removeClass('alert-danger').addClass('alert-success');
        message.text(response);
        setTimeout(function () {
            message.fadeOut();
        }, 2000);
        form.find('input:not([type="submit"]), textarea').val('');
    }

    // fail function
    function fail_func(data) {
        message.fadeIn().removeClass('alert-success').addClass('alert-success');
        message.text(data.responseText);
        setTimeout(function () {
            message.fadeOut();
        }, 2000);
    }
    
    form.submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        form_data = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: form.attr('action'),
            data: form_data
        })
        .done(done_func)
        .fail(fail_func);
    });
    
})(jQuery);
```

mail.php:

```
<?php

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

        # FIX: Replace this email with recipient email
        $mail_to = "haroutdeurdulian@gmail.com";
        
        # Sender Data
        $subject = trim($_POST["subject"]);
        $name = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," ") , strip_tags(trim($_POST["name"])));
        $email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        $phone = trim($_POST["phone"]);
        $message = trim($_POST["message"]);
        
        if ( empty($name) OR !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) OR empty($phone) OR empty($subject) OR empty($message)) {
            # Set a 400 (bad request) response code and exit.
            http_response_code(400);
            echo "Please complete the form and try again.";
            exit;
        }
        
        # Mail Content
        $content = "Name: $name\n";
        $content .= "Email: $email\n\n";
        $content .= "Phone: $phone\n";
        $content .= "Message:\n$message\n";

        # email headers.
        $headers = "From: $name <$email>";

        # Send the email.
        $success = mail($mail_to, $subject, $content, $headers);
        if ($success) {
            # Set a 200 (okay) response code.
            http_response_code(200);
            echo "Thank You! Your message has been sent.";
        } else {
            # Set a 500 (internal server error) response code.
            http_response_code(500);
            echo "Oops! Something went wrong, we couldn't send your message.";
        }

    } else {
        # Not a POST request, set a 403 (forbidden) response code.
        http_response_code(403);
        echo "There was a problem with your submission, please try again.";
    }

?>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I can not see that you have initialized `PHPmailer` anywhere in your code OR is it setup already in your config file ?

Comment: this only works in a server and don't forget to check spam folder as it will be in spam 98% of time

Comment: is the server sending other emails succuesfully ? you need to configure PHPmailer to send emails to this email and all that data.

Comment: This email system can send without phpmailer i checked on it